# Upload documents from a web from in react using FormData() is not working

Tags: reactjs, upload, redux-saga, form-data

I am creating a simple form in react with a couple of fields and an button to select a file from your pc and upload it. But I have a problem with uploading the file. I am using FormData() for creating the "file" object. This is the code from my Saga (I am using redux saga also):

```
function* upload(action) {
    const payload = action.payload
    const data = new FormData()
    payload.files.map((file) => {
        data.append("file", file)
    })
    data.append("code", payload.code)

   .....
}
```

The problem is that  data object is constantly empty and in the back-end I am sending a null object. Can someone check if I am using FormData() wrong or why is data object empty? Or maybe suggest me a way of how I can develop a functionality for uploading a file in my form?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the error is in the backend. Can you add more details about what you're using server-side please?

Comment: I am using [FromForm] in the endpoint for taking the data( the File object). I forgot to mention that in the POST method in 'Headers' in the 'Network' section in my browser there was nothing send, the model is missing. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I think that `data.append("file", file)` is not working (is not appending the file)